# Update Database Row on HTML Button Click

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server, ajax, sql-update

I currently have a table that has data imported from a SQL Server database. The table also has an edit button for each row where I can choose to edit a certain row if I want to. On Save, it should then fire up an AJAX request to my `update.php` script which runs a SQL update query. However, whenever I go to update the row and click save, I get this error:

> 500 (Internal Server Error)

I can see in my console, however, that it is logging the correct values that I need so I am guessing the problem is either AJAX related or somewhere in my `update.php` script. What is wrong with my following code so that I can have the update function working correctly?

The 2 columns that are necessary for my update problem and the edit button that are all inside a table:

```
<td class="sku" id="sku-<?php echo intval ($rows['SKU'])?>"><?php echo $rows['SKU']?></td>
<td class="group_id" style="display: none" id="group_id-<?php echo intval ($rows['SKU Group'])?>"><?php echo $rows['Group_ID']?></td>
<td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit"></td>
```

Switch statement that gets the value and AJAX request:

```
var dict = {}; 
elements.each(function (index, element) {
  var type = $(this).attr('class');
  var value = (element.tagName == 'INPUT') ? $(this).val() : $(this).text();
  console.log(type);
  // ----- Switch statement that provides validation for each table cell -----
  switch (type) {
    case "group_id":
          dict["Group_ID"] = value.trim();
      break;
    case "sku":
      if (!$.isNumeric(value)) {
        isValid = false;
        errors += "Please enter a valid SKU\n";
      }
      if (isValid) {
          dict["SKU"] = value;
      }
      break;
  }
})
if (isValid) {
    console.log(dict);
  $this.val('Edit');
  tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
  var request = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "update.php",
      data: dict
    });

    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
      if(JSON.parse(response) == true){
        console.log("row updated");
      } else {
        console.log("row failed to updated");
        console.log(response);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(jqXHR);
      }
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Log the error to the console
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.error(
            "The following error occurred: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called regardless
    // if the request failed or succeeded
    request.always(function () {

    });
} else {
  alert(errors);
}
```

Update.php script:

```
<?php

  $SKU = $_POST['SKU'];
  $Group_ID = $_POST['Group_ID'];

  $host="xxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbName="xxxxx"; 
  $dbUser="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbPass="xxxxxxxxxx";

  $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".$host.";Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);

  $sql = "UPDATE SKU_Group_Index SET SKU = :SKU WHERE Group_ID = :Group_ID";

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindValue(':SKU', $SKU);
  $stmt->bindValue(':Group_ID', $Group_ID)  
  $result = $stmt->execute();
  echo json_encode($result);
  if(!$result) {
      echo json_encode(sqlsrv_errors());
  }

?>
```

EDIT: 
This is an example of what my `console.log(dict);` looks like:

> Object {SKU: "12345", Group_ID: "456"}

Comment: Can you please add the content of `console.log(dict);`

Comment: @Hackerman edited!

Comment: On your update php script, replace all the code with a simple `echo json_encode(array("message"=>"test"));`...if that works and we get rid of the error 500, then we can say that there is something wrong with the pdo connection maybe :)

Comment: After replacing all my code with that line, it looks like the error 500 is now gone

Comment: *500 (Internal Server Error)* - check your logs.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - Can you please stop being a few seconds faster than me? :o That's just...  rude.. or something. :)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson my bad; I used to type 90wpm and down to only 30 :(

Comment: I think that the problem is with the pdo connection...now with you need to check if your post vars or your connections vars have the right values :)